# View is not showing in backbone.marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I was trying to build an example to demonstrate the region and layout thing of Backbone.Marionette . But i stuck in the layout , though i am calling the layout.region.show() , it's not showing anywhere in the DOM.

Full example can be found in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdsahib/MWmhe/4/).

This is the layout part :

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
template: "#layout-template",
  el : "layout-containr",

regions: {
  menu: "#menu",
  content: "#content"
}
```

});

Layout template:

```
<script id="layout-template" type="text/template">
<section>
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</section>
```

Here is how i am showing the layout :

```
var layout = new AppLayout();
layout.render();
layout.menu.show(gridView);
```

GridView's definition can be found here:

```
 var GridView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
itemView: GridRow,
  el:'#menu'

});
```

Full example can be found in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdsahib/MWmhe/4/).

And i have a complimentary question :

How layout will know ***where it should be attached*** ???
I did not find it anywhere in the net which makes me sure that i am missing some concepts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bigger region to show the layout, in application level.

Usually when you initialize a Marionette application, you will have some top-leve regions to show the layout you want to render later.

```
App.addInitializer =>
  App.addRegions
    menuRegion: '#header'
    contentRegion: '#stage' # These DOM come from your application layout
```

And then in your controller, you show these layout in your top-leve region.

```
indexShow: ->

  layout = new App.Layouts.SomeLayout()
  App.contentRegion.show(layout)

  someView = new App.Views.SomeView()
  anotherView = new App.Views.AnotherView()

  layout.someSubRegion.show(someView)
  layout.anotherSubRegion.show(anotherView)
```

And, you usually don't need an `el` either in your view or layout

Comment: what i understand is i need to add a app lever region and call the app.region.show(layout) . Did i get it right?

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob Exactly

Comment: Updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdsahib/MWmhe/7/) accordingly. Can you have a look pleas ? I can sense that , i am this close to the solution :(

Comment: You forgot to start your Marionette app..   After `MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application;` you need to `MyApp.start()`

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob If you don't mind, you can send me your code to my email: yuhang.service@gmail.com. I will take a look on that